# Replace 'new line' in XSLT

Tags: xml, xslt

There is an XML tag like below.

```
<inputT>This is line one
  This is line two.
  This is line three.</inputT>
```

I want to create JSON file from that XML file using an XSLT. And, the relevant JSON field for the above XML element should be like below.

```
"output": "This is line one###This is line two.###This is line three."
```

I tried with below XSLT command to achieve this.

```
<xsl:text>"output":"</xsl:text>
    <xsl:variable name="inputText" select="inputT"/>
    <xsl:value-of select="replace($inputText, '&#10;', '###')" />
<xsl:text>"</xsl:text>
```

But it didn't give the expected result. How can I improve my xslt code to achive my goal?

Comment: So which result do you get?

Comment: At http://xsltransform.hikmatu.com/6qM2e2r your snippet incorporated into a minimal but complete sample gives the output `"output":"This is line one###  This is line two.###  This is line three."` so the newline replacement does happen. You haven't told us in what way you didn't get "the expected result". Any error?

Comment: I changed my transformation tool and checked again. The issue was in the transformation tool

Comment: `replace` is only supported in XSLT 2.0 and above, so maybe the first transformation tool you used was only XSLT 1.0?

Answer (score 1):

```
<xsl:template match="@*|node()">
        <xsl:copy>
            <xsl:apply-templates select="@*|node()"/>
        </xsl:copy>
    </xsl:template>
    <xsl:template match="inputT">
        <xsl:text>"output":"</xsl:text> <xsl:if test="matches(.,'\n')">
            <xsl:value-of select="replace(.,'\n    ',' ')"/>
        </xsl:if><xsl:text>"</xsl:text>
    </xsl:template>
You may try like this
```